# Running FIO test in certain section of hard disk drive

Tags: performance

I am trying to use FIO to perform performance test on HDDs. I want to restrict random read test in particular section of HDD (For eg: Random read in first 1TB of HDDs). Can someone please let me know which argument in the config file I should to restrict test run in certain section of drives.

Answer (score 0):

The most universal solution would be to partition you HDDs in the way you like (e.g. create a 1TB partition in the beginning of the drive) and run your tests on that partition.

A simpler solution is to run tests directly on the device file and use [`offset=int`](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-offset) and [`size=int`](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-size) parameters to define which part of the HDD is to be tested. Of course, you won't be able to run filesystem tests on an arbitrary HDD region without partitioning and formatting it properly first, in which case, see above.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I looked for the size=int option for FIO. It looked to me like size option will allow to run IO of that particular size(as compared to restrict IO operation with the specified size). I am getting this from following link: https://linux.die.net/man/1/fio (plz search size). Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @Prabhat Your understanding is incomplete and Dmitry's answer is correct. As stated in the links off his question, fio's `size` option can control the amount AND the end of the range. Fio actually has a separate option [`io_size`](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-io-size) to control just the amount.